# Most efficient way to construct a square matrix in numpy using values from a generator

Tags: python, matrix, numpy

I have a generator `g` which I know in advance that would return `n` items. Each item `i` is of the following structure:

`t_i:(e_i, b_i)`

`t_i` is a tuple of variable size, and may contain any ordered subsequence of list `(1,...,n)`. For example, for `n=6`, `t_1=(1, 3, 4)`, `t_2=(2, 4, 6)` and so on.

`e_i` is a number (float/integer), and `b_i` is a boolean (which is not really used here).

**I wonder what is the most efficient way to construct a `n x n` matrix (using numpy array) using `g` such that**:

Each row `i` of the matrix corresponds to `t_i:(e_i, b_i)` in a way that: 1. the row elements (in the matrix) whose positions appear in `t_i` should be set using `e_i`; 2. other row elements are default to `0`.

So for example, given that row `2` of a `8 x 8` matrix corresponds to item `t_2:(e_2, b_2) = (2, 4, 6):(13, True)`, this row should be then set as `(0, 13, 0, 13, 0, 13, 0, 0)`. Notice that we are not using zero-indexing here for the numbers in `t_2` (or `t_i` in general).

An obvious way is to construct a `n x n` matrix in advance, and then go through each item return by the generator, and set each row sequentially based on the item. But I feel there must be some more efficient way to do this given the power of Python and that of `numpy` in particular.

Comment: A code snippet is sometimes worth 1000 words (othertimes, the opposite is true).  In any event, it would be helpful to me at least if you would show the "obvious" way as code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Constructing an n-by-n matrix in Numpy is easy and fairly efficient. By using advanced indexing to set the rows, we can get a pretty simple and efficient implementation:

```
arr = np.zeros((n,n))
for i,(t,e,b) in enumerate(g):
    arr[i,np.array(t) - 1] = e
```

Note this assumes that `g` produces tuples of the form `(ti, ei, bi)`.

Comment: I think advanced indexing by using `array()` is the key part here. Thanks for pointing it out.